# How to pass text from one javascript function to another using ("+ text here +")

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I know how to pass a number from one function to another, e.g:

```
button.onclick = function()
{
    csInterface.evalScript("ResizeCustom(" + 1234 + ")");

};
```

which would get picked up in the relevant line of the called function using:

```
function ResizeCustom(inputvalue) {

    desc1.putUnitDouble(cTID('Wdth'), cTID('#Pxl'), inputvalue);

};
```

This works successfully for me only using a number.

How do I achieve the same thing if I want to use text?

The text needs to be picked up in the receiving function in quotation marks, e.g:

```
function SelectLayer(inputtext) {

    ref1.putName(cTID('Lyr '), "Background");

};
```

where I want "Background" to be replaced by inputtext, and by extension the text I enter in the first function.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You pass strings, by passing strings as arguments i.e. 

`myFunc("my string arg")` 

so you would simply call SelectLayer with a string. 

```function SelectLayer(inputtext) {

    ref1.putName(cTID('Lyr '), inputtext);

}```

then

`SelectLayer("my string arg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still recommend checking Davide Barranca's blog HTML extension panels (https://www.davidebarranca.com/2014/01/html-panels-tips-4-passing-objects-from-html-to-jsx/), all the questions you're asking here are answered there.

To pass your string use `csInterface.evalScript("ResizeCustom('String')");` or `csInterface.evalScript("ResizeCustom('"+strVar+"')");`